# How to add formatter when creating jqgrid dynamic column

Tags: json

I am currently creating dynamic column for `jqGrid` and I'm still encountering an error on parsing the string unexpected token e error. How to add formatter when creating `jqGrid` dynamic column? here's what I have done so far.

```
sColumnModels += ", { \"name\": \"" + Convert.ToDateTime(item).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy").Replace("/", "-").Trim() +
                 "\", \"width\": 100, \"align\": \"center\", \"frozen\": true, \"formatter\": \"function customFormatter(cellValue, options, rowObject) { alert(cellValue); }\" }";
```

Comment: What is the error? "*some error on parsing*" is unanswerable.